# Dexie -> column names as variables

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

We are updating/inserting on multiple tables that each has the same basic fields with a prefix.

We want to use variables to change the column names.

e.g. `db.friends.update(2, {name: "Number 2"})`

we would like to use the column "name" as a variable

would this please be possible

thanx

Answer (score 0):

In modern javascript dynamic property names can be specified around brackets as the following example:

```
async function updateField(id, fieldName, fieldValue) {
  await db.friends.update(id, {[fieldName]: fieldValue});
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, getting the consult package once we have basics running